# Getting formatted response from Chatgpt api

Tags: chat, chatbot, next.js13, openai-api

I’d like to get responses from ChatGPT in a neat and organized format, like bullet points. For instance, if I ask about five uses of Next.js, I’d prefer the answers to be presented as five distinct bullet points instead of a long paragraph.also i would like to know on how to acheive streaming of responses in next js and open ai api

Could you please guide me on how to achieve this? I believe it’ll make the responses more readable and to the point.

how to do that????

I have written the api for calling the chatgpt responses, but when i show them its just a big paragraph even if i have prompted to beforehand to give them in a formatted way